# Free function activates a breakpoint

Tags: c, linked-list, free

I'm trying to call the free function to deallocate nodes from a linked list, but whenever I try to do so the IDE (CLion) stops the program and gives me a SIGTRAP (Trace/breakpoint trap).

Here is the linked list:

```
struct node{
    int score;
    int index;
    struct node* nextNode;
};

typedef struct node* List;
```

Now the functions that initalizes and links the list:

```
List list= malloc(sizeof(List));
list->index=-1;
list->score=-10;
list->next=NULL;
min++;  min--;
List temp;
for(int i=sizeGrafi-1; i>0; i--){
     temp= malloc(sizeof(List));
     temp->index=i;
     temp->score=-10;
     temp->next=list;
     nodiDaVisitare=temp;
}
```

And here's the funcition that should delete and deallocate a node (to avoid useless code I'll
just post the case in which the node to remove is the head):

```
List removeNode(List list){
    Lista temp= malloc(sizeof(List));
    temp=list;
    list=list->next;
    free(temp);
    return list;
}
```

I tried looking at similiar questions, but I couldn't find what is wrong with my code. The crash happens when the free function gets called.

EDIT: I followed the advice to remove the typedef

```
typedef struct node* List;
```

,rewrite all lists as Node*, with Node defined as:

```
typedef struct node{
    int punteggio;
    int indice;
    struct nodo* successivo;
}Node;
```

and using the right size (i.e. sizeof(Node)) in mallocs.
Now the function free doesn't seem to give any problems. Thank you all.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(List))` allocates enough memory to store a pointer.  You probably meant to allocate `malloc(sizeof (struct node))`.

Comment: Never hide a pointer types behind a typedef. Otherways errors like pointed out in the previous comment  happen very easily. Never hide pointer types behind a typedef only adds confusion. Remove `typedef struct node* List;` alltogether and use `struct node*`.

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. There are most likely other errors in the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Lista temp= malloc(sizeof(List));
    temp=list;
    list=list->next;
```

You `malloc` memory and store the reference to it in `temp`. Then you assign `temp` with `list`. The previous value is lost.

Then you try to free that pointer - thus problems with `free`.

BTW that function makes no sense at all. It is hard to understand what you want to achieve.

Additionally, never hide the pointers behind `typedef`s.

Comment: @SergeLover but this chaotic makes no sense anyway

Comment: The code became very choatic because I tried to change the code in any way possible to try to make it work (for example initializing temp with a malloc before making it equal to list).
Initially I tried to assign temp as the second element of the list, free hte list, and then returning temp (sorry but I don't know how to post formatted code in a reply).
The idea of the function is to eliminate a node from the linked list and free the its allocated memory (and, as you can see, I'm struggling to do so).